# Sequelize WHERE Parameter Error: 'email' has invalid 'undefined' value

Tags: javascript, express, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize to build a user registration feature in my Node.js application. When I try to check for an existing user using the email parameter, I'm encountering the following error: "WHERE parameter 'email' has invalid 'undefined' value."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYp2Y.png)
in db it is DataTypes.STRING

I've checked the request body to ensure that the 'email' field is being sent.
I've verified that my server is set up with the express.json() middleware for parsing JSON.
I expect the code to correctly query the database for an existing user based on the provided email address and handle the case where the user already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve checked your code I’m wondering that you register middleware express urlencoded
Please check your main express code maybe you forget to add it

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: i have added it in index.js file already. its not working

Answer (score 0):

i'm not intersted with Sequelize so maybe my answer is wrong but anyway
the first thing i'm intersted in your code is `**async**(req,res)=>{}` so you have a reason to use async and await for your controller right???
yeah you have and what's the reason? so in Sequelize when you want to use findOne() you need to use **await** for that but you didn't use it so it's doesnt return anything!

i'm get this problem so much at mongoDB so don't worry!
so you need to do this:

```
const find = await findOne(where:{email})

if(find)
//do code
```

Comment: Actually i'm using await. idk why i removed it when i took screenshots but its not working with await either